# How can I fix keyboard layouts changing very slowly?

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

When I have 2 keyboard layouts (russian and english) they change slowly. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in elementary OS 5.0. Whole system stutters a bit when changing layouts. There is no fix for this problem as for now, but I made a workaround:

- Save this [script](https://gist.github.com/konchunas/ab805f7ce8d883ac5befc7edc9b333e7) somewhere locally
- If you have more than two layouts change the value of `LAYOUT_COUNT` inside
- Assign executable bit to your script using `chmod +x`
- Go to Settings -> Keyboard
- Select "Disabled" in "Switch layout" field
- Now go to Shortcuts tab, select "Custom" category and press "+"
- Copy and paste full path to your script to the first column
- Assign your preferred shortcut in the second column

Please Note that this method may not allow you to assign some specific shortcuts, but system-default Alt+Space works fine.

Here are links to tracking [issue](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/220) and [comment](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/220#issuecomment-433351489) of guy who discovered the workaround